# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8.2

Estoy tratando de hacer una conexión con `java` en `Netbeans` a una base de datos MySQL en Workbench, pero a la hora de establecer la conexión me sale este error:

```
"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

¿Que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este error ocurre porque estás utilizando `MySQL Connector/J 5.1.45` o anterior. `MySQL 8` introdujo un nuevo mecanismo de autenticación que no es compatible con las versiones antiguas del driver.

Asegúrate de usar una versión reciente (actualmente la última es la `8.0.28`). La dependencia en tu `pom.xml` debería lucir:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.28</version>
</dependency>
```

O bien puedes descargar el `jar` manualmente de https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Alternativamente (no recomendado) y solo si es necesario para dar soporte a sistemas antiguos, MySQL describe el procedimiento para desactivar por defecto este nuevo mecanismo de autenticación, y también da información para desactivarlo solo para ciertos clientes. Refiérase a https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/old-client.html

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si funciono.

Comment: Descargue manualmente el archivo jar 8.0.28